# Does Cordova MapKit Plugin have native features and does it behave as a html-element?

Tags: cordova, maps, phonegap-plugins

I want to use a map in a phonegap application and I would prefer to have a native look by using the [Cordova MapKit Plugin](https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit) but it's not clear to me how it works.

Does the MapKit plugin support Features like the user location - `setMyLocationEnabled()` or the current traffic - `setTrafficEnabled()`? (and similar functions for iOS) If yes: how can I use them with the plugin?

Is the loaded Map even part of the webview? Can I create html-elements which are on top of the mapview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin creates a view that contains a map view and places it overtop of the web view. You are not able to place HTML elements on top of it.

By default the plugin displays the user's current location, if you wanted to though you could change it, you would just either need to hard code it in the MapKit.m file or put something like `[options objectForKey@"showUserLocation"]` and then pass it as a setting when you instantiate the map.

As far as I know, and have researched, MapKit does not support a traffic layer. You would need to integrate some other service in with the plugin or look for some other plugin if you really need a traffic layer.